# How can I see what version of Mirror's Edge I have installed on my PC?

Tags: mirrors-edge

Usually the version of the game is listed in the lower right corner (or some corner) of the games main screen. But I can't find it anywhere here.

I'm getting freezes in the game and after some reading it seems there's a patch out for that problem. I just need to find the version of the game I have.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer specific to just Mirrors Edge but to any application on Windows.

If you right click the games main executable (.exe) and choose "Preferences" --> "Details" (Windows 7 - English version) you are able to see the version of the program.

There is a good chance that the version specified here is the same as the version number used towards the public i.e. in the changelog for the patch but if it isn't, it might at least give you an indication.